# A better way to reload() on click in React? Possibly with a useCallback hook?

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

After many infinite loops, I got the state to work and the page reloads on the click of my own refresh button.

I watched a few useMemo() and useCallback() tuts on Youtube but I haven't used the hooks enough to understand them.
I was able to get it working but was wondering if anyone wanted to advise or hint at a better way to proceed...?

Also the useEffect with a variable dependency array didn't work for me though it seemed like the best solution originally.

```
function NavButtons(props) {
    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
    function Refresh () {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <RefreshIcon onClick={Refresh} />         
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Actually the solution here is not updating state.

Comment: Yes, you're not using the state. Why do you want to reload the page?

Comment: Because there is a Math.random function running on an array of news on every refresh. So I wanted to give the user a button on the page so they don't have to rely on browser buttons to refresh the news.

Comment: You could set the result of that function in the state and call that function onClick. Usually with React you don't need to reload a page.

Comment: I will have to figure out what initial state to use.

Comment: You can use an empty array. Then you call the function the first time in a useEffect with an empty dependencies array.

Comment: "*Because there is a `Math.random` function running on an array of news on every refresh*" -- then you could just rerun the part of code responsible for generating the numbers. Store *those numbers* in a state, so your app will rerender automatically when they're changed. Reloading the entire page for that (especially that you're instructing the browser to redownload cached stuff) is a huge overhead for this!

Comment: Hmmm... I see your point about the overhead. Ok let me try to work it out.

Comment: ```const integer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)```

        ```return topNews[integer]```

Comment: That's the part of the code responsible for generating the numbers.